# Overwrite colorscheme syntax highlighting

Tags: colorscheme, vimdiff

*/* This is coming directly from Molokai's [issue #36](https://github.com/tomasr/molokai/issues/36). */*

## The problem

[*Molokai*](https://github.com/tomasr/molokai) is a very nice theme for *Vim* but it has a terrible *vimdiff* highlighting (see left split, last 5 lines). `+` are not *green* and `-` are not *red*.

[image: Bad syntax highlighting]

I've been suggested by **justinmk**@GitHub to use the following `~/.vimrc` ([here](https://gist.github.com/Atcold/f3b75884c6b2ba18ff26)'s the *gist*).

```
syntax enable
let s:color_override_dark = '
    \ if &background == "dark"
    \ | hi StatusLine    guifg=#000000 guibg=#ffffff gui=NONE  ctermfg=16 ctermbg=15     cterm=NONE
    \ | hi CursorLine    guibg=#293739 ctermbg=236
    \ | hi PmenuSel      guibg=#0a9dff guifg=white   gui=NONE  ctermbg=39 ctermfg=white  cterm=NONE
    \ | hi PmenuSbar     guibg=#857f78
    \ | hi PmenuThumb    guifg=#242321
    \ | hi WildMenu      gui=NONE cterm=NONE guifg=#f8f6f2 guibg=#0a9dff ctermfg=255 ctermbg=39
    \ | hi DiffAdd       guifg=#ffffff guibg=#006600 gui=NONE  ctermfg=231  ctermbg=22   cterm=NONE 
    \ | hi DiffChange    guifg=#ffffff guibg=#007878 gui=NONE  ctermfg=231  ctermbg=30   cterm=NONE 
    \ | hi DiffDelete    guifg=#ff0101 guibg=#9a0000 gui=NONE  ctermfg=196  ctermbg=88   cterm=NONE 
    \ | hi DiffText      guifg=#000000 guibg=#ffb733 gui=NONE  ctermfg=000  ctermbg=214  cterm=NONE 
    \ | hi MatchParen    guifg=NONE   guibg=NONE gui=underline ctermfg=NONE ctermbg=NONE cterm=underline
    \ | endif
    \'

if has('vim_starting') "only on startup
  exe 'autocmd ColorScheme * '.s:color_override_dark
  " expects &runtimepath/colors/{name}.vim.
  silent! colorscheme molokai
endif
```

which unfortunately does not work for some reasons.
Can someone point out what has been done wrongly?

---

## The solution

Inserting the following code into `~/.vimrc` fixes the problem stated above.

```
colorscheme molokai
" Better gitcommit messages
hi diffAdded   ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=46  cterm=NONE guibg=NONE guifg=#00FF00 gui=NONE
hi diffRemoved ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=196 cterm=NONE guibg=NONE guifg=#FF0000 gui=NONE
hi link diffLine String
hi link diffSubname Normal
```

And here we have a before / after :)

[image: Before / after]

### Further information

It is possible to [remap `F10` to *show me what syntax is this*](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor). Then, one can modify what s/he feels needs some adjustments, as I've done for the 'strong' `diffLine` and to the 'green' `diffSubname`.

Comment: Why don't you simply edit the colorscheme itself?

Comment: I did it, as did the first user in the issue, but with no results. It's like the colorscheme overwrites the `Diff*`... (On the first line I've linked the issue.)

Comment: I'm confused. Why are there `\\` at the start of each line?

Comment: @muru, `:help new-line-continuation`.

Comment: @romainl wow. That is horribly counter-intuitive when compared to other languages.

Comment: @muru, do you really expect vimscript to be intuitive?

Comment: @romainl -_- indeed not. :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`DiffAdd` and `DiffDelete` are only used when actually *performing* a diff (`$ vim -d foo.txt bar.txt`, `$ vimdiff foo.txt bar.txt`, `$ git mergetool`, etc.); those highlight groups are totally irrelevant, here.

The highlight groups used for added and deleted lines when *reading* a diff file are `diffAdded` and `diffRemoved`.

Adding the lines below between line 272 and line 274 of `molokai.vim` should fix your problem:

```
hi diffAdded   ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=108 cterm=NONE guibg=NONE guifg=#87af87 gui=NONE
hi diffRemoved ctermbg=NONE ctermfg=131 cterm=NONE guibg=NONE guifg=#af5f5f gui=NONE
```

(Those are the colors used in [my own colorscheme](https://github.com/romainl/Apprentice), use the ones you want.)

Comment: **Wow!!!** It did work! Where did you get the two commands `diffAdded` and `diffRemoved`? Let's say I'd like to change the bright green used after the `@@` with the theme's orange, how would I find that?

Comment: OK, found it [here](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Identify_the_syntax_highlighting_group_used_at_the_cursor). Now I'm in control! Uhahaha!